# DTMB compatible streamer server

Tags: video-streaming, signal

I know TvHeadend is an open source streamer server that supports a wide variety of Digital Television standards. TvHeadend doens't supports DTMB according to the official site. Is there any open source streamer server TvHeadend-alike that supports this standard?

I originally considered posting this question on Signal Proccesing's forum but questions there are more focused on maths. Sorry if this is not the right place to ask about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

tvheadend supports dtmb, you can use some compatible usb receivers just like rqd and tbs to receive them. Althrough you cannot found the option "dtmb" in tvheadend, but if you have the right receiver and choose the "dvb-t", it still works :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).